# How can I properly load fonts in a generated PDF from a razor view in Xamarin MVVMCross?

Tags: c#, xamarin, razor, fonts, mvvmcross

I have been working on a custom PDF generation feature in an MVVMCross application. I'm using a razor template in my Core project that ultimately generates the PDF on both iOS and Android. For this PDF, I have to use custom truetype fonts, but I have been unable to reference them properly since the HTML from the razor file is passed along the application as a string and then loaded into the PDF file on different devices. The only way I found around this so far is to include the base64 version of each font in the razor file itself, but this ends up slowing down the file whenever I try to open it to make changes. Is there any way to reference the fonts properly so that they are available when the html is written to the PDF?

I was also able to get it working by adding the Base64 fonts to a constants file and then referencing those constants, but that just moves the slow file load time from the razor file to my constants file.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to resolve this by just setting the BaseUrls for each of the view projects seperately to reference the resource folders containing the fonts.